# how to transition image in the same way as background?

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to transition image and the background together.

css

```
#div{
  background:black;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  transition: background 2.3s linear;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
  $("#div").mouseover(function(){
    var $p = $("#div");
    $p.css("background-color","yellow");
    $(".img").attr("src","https://pt.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Mushroom-1UP-icon.png");
  });
});
```

I'd like to transition the image with the background when mouse over. is it possible? how can I do this? jquery or css?

http://jsfiddle.net/ykrp7zbo/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily transition the source of an IMG element. Instead, use a div and place the images you want as css background image. For example (with minimal changes to your example):

```
--- HTML ---
<div id="div">
   <div class="img"></div>
</div>

--- CSS ---
#div {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: background 2.3s linear;
}
div.img {
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png');
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background 2.3s linear;
}

---- JS ----
$(function(){
    $("#div").mouseover(function(){
      var $p = $("#div");
      $p.css("background-color","yellow");
      $(".img").css({backgroundImage: "url(https://pt.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Mushroom-1UP-icon.png)"});
    });
});
```

Put your initial image in the CSS, and your updated image is in the javascript, which modifies the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the images in your HTML code, you have to set them and deal with they opacity, like this:

```
--- Html ---
<div id=div>
  <img class=img1 src=http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png>
  <img class=img2 src=https://pt.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Mushroom-1UP-icon.png>
</div>

--- CSS ---
#div{
  background:black;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  transition: background 2.3s linear;
  position: relative;
}
#div img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 2.3s linear;
}
.img2{opacity: 0;}

--- JS ---
$(function(){
  $("#div").mouseover(function(){
    var $p = $("#div");
    $p.css("background-color","yellow");
    $(".img1").css("opacity", 0);
    $(".img2").css("opacity", 1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing with pure CSS and hover effects.

```
`#div{
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  z-index:-999;
  position:absolute;
}

.img{
  opacity:1;
  position:relative;
}

.img2{
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  z-index:-1;
}

#div:hover{
  background:yellow;
}
#div:hover>.img{
   transition: opacity 2.3s ease-in-out;
   opacity:0;
}
#div:hover>.img2{
    opacity:1;
}
```

`and HTML`

```
<div id=div>

    <img class=img src=http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png>
    <img class="img2" src="https://pt.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Mushroom-1UP-icon.png" alt="">  

 </div>
```

`

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/xhgdy26w/3/